# Group By with multiple Objects vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I have a list as following

```
list1 =  [
   {meal: {id: 1, version: 0}, type: {id: 2, version: 0}, adjCount: 1, systemCount: 0},
   {meal: {id: 1, version: 0}, type: {id: 2, version: 0}, adjCount: 2, systemCount: 0},
   {meal: {id: 2, version: 0}, type: {id: 1, version: 0}, adjCount: 4, systemCount: 0},
   {meal: {id: 2, version: 0}, type: {id: 1, version: 0}, adjCount: 7, systemCount: 0},
]
```

I'm looking for a result such as it returns both mealId and type id with it's respective totals
As

```
{meal: {id: 1, version: 0}, type: {id: 2, version: 0}, adjCount: 3, systemCount: 0},
{meal: {id: 2, version: 0}, type: {id: 1, version: 0}, adjCount: 11, systemCount: 0}
```

I tried Using Linq with following code

```
List.GroupBy(Function(myItem) New MyObject With {.mealTypeId = myItem.Meal.Id, .countTypeId = MyItem.Count.Id}).
Select(Function(g) New With
 {
    .MealTypeId = g.Key.MealTypeId,
    .CountTypeId = g.Key.CountTypeId,
    .AdjustmentCount = g.Sum(Function(i) i.AdjustmentCount),
    .SystemCount = g.Sum(Function(i) i.SystemCount)
 }
```

but it doesn't return the expected output. Any Help will be greatly appreciated, I very rarely ask questions here so please forgive any mistakes I might have done in describing the issue.

Comment: Probably doing reference comparison on the `MyObject` instances, but I don't have time now to confirm. If I'm write, you want to implement something like GetHashCode() that only looks at the right fields to use as the key selector function.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn will you able to help me with the code, I mostly work on the front end and have no idea what do you mean by Implement the GetHaseCode function. I would really appreciate that. Thank you!

Comment: Consider using a dictionary approach, instead of an obtuse group by clause. For the dictionary, the keys will be whatever you need the grouping to be, and the value will be an object where the counts can be updated. So, iterate over `list1` and when the dictionary key does not exist, add the new key and value; when the key does it exist, increment the counts.